# React-native Redux counter example: explain about reducer

Tags: javascript, react-native, redux

I am learning react-native and redux from this article,
https://github.com/alinz/example-react-native-redux/tree/master/Counter, and I want to understand why inside folder `reducers`, there is an `index.js` with content as below:

```
import counter from './counter';
export {
   counter
};
```

I dont understand why we need this, since in the same folder `reducers`, there is `counter.js` with content as follow

```
export default function counter(state = initialState, action = {}) {
   ...
}
```

it already export default `counter`, why does `index.js` do it again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your application grows with lots of reducers, you can 'import nameHere from reducers'. (it is just a convenience). Also, your code is easier to 'refactor' ussually, since you don't need to change the actual import, but you can for instance import multiple from this same file.

```
// this is preferred
import { ScalesReducer, BoxReducer } from './reducers';

// does the same, takes more space (more distraction in your code)
import ScalesReducer from './reducers/ScalesReducer';
import BoxReducer from './reducers/BoxReducer';
```

Comment: Thank you, if you dont mind, I want to ask 1 more thing about import. `import reducer from './app/reducers'`, but inside folder `app`, there is no file `reducers.js`, but only `index.js` and `recipies.js`. Does it mean that when it cannot find `reducers.js`, it will fall back to find `index.js`

Comment: Hi Thang, It will indeed take the index of that folder (this can be configured, but I assume you are using a default setup).

http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/ExampleTodoList.html   (here you will find a more practical example)